# ImportError: No module named MySQLdb - Debian 6.0

Tags: python, mysql, debian, mysql-python

I got a problem in Python while try to import mysql. The beginning of my code is (I'm using monkeyrunner to run script) :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys  
import MySQLdb
.
.
.
etc
```

Each time I try to run the code, I got the current error:

```
dani@debian:~/public/Yandex Maps Test$ monkeyrunner test.py
130413 00:49:22.066:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] Script terminated due to an exception
130413 00:49:22.066:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dani/public/Yandex Maps Test/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb

130413 00:49:22.066:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] at org.python.core.PyException.fillInStackTrace(PyException.java:70)
.
.
.
etc
```

I tried to re-install mysql for python:

```
sudo apt-get reinstall python-mysqldb mysql-server
```

But nothing helped. Any ideas or tips?

Regards,,,

Comment: Do you use [`virtualenv`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)?

Comment: No, the only thing I installed for Python in MySQL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `monkeyrunner` isn't the same interpreter as your default system Python, and doesn't share the same site-packages, etc.

That `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top of your script is misleading. If you actually run your script with `/usr/bin/env python test.py`, or just `./test.py` (assuming `chmod +x`), it will work. But you're not, you're running it with `monkeyrunner`.

So, nothing you install for your system Python is going to be usable within `monkeyrunner`. You have to install it for `monkeyrunner` instead.

Moreover, as [the docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) say:

> The monkeyrunner tool uses Jython, a implementation of Python that uses the Java programming language.

While Jython is Python, and implements the same Python language and (almost) standard library as CPython, it doesn't implement the CPython C API, and therefore can't use C-API extensions like MySQLdb. (They're actually working on a clever wrapper that will change this in the future, but that doesn't help you today.)

There are other MySQL drivers that work with both CPython and Jython (because they use pure Python), such as [`PyMySQL`](https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL). But the simplest solution is to just use Java's `JDBC` drivers. As the [Jython FAQ](http://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/JythonModules) suggests, the easiest way to do that is:

> Use [`zxJDBC`](http://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/zxjdbc.html) which gives data database connectivity from Jython using the Python DB API 2.0 interface…

Unlike using JDBC directly, using `zxJDBC` often means you only need to change one line in your MySQLdb code to make it work.

Comment: Thank you a lot, now I understand better how this stuff works correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

i have the same question with u.
and i tried to use zxJDBC to fix it.
but when i run the script, it cannot find "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver" either "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver". Even i put mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar and zxJDBC.jar under system CLASSPATH.
i tried run this script under jython. it worked.
so i think this question is related with monkeyrunner.